# How could I deploy a Windows Phone 8 app from server?

Tags: windows-phone-8, mdm

Our goal is to publish a Windows Phone 8 application directly on a web site. This web site is an enterprise application open to a large panel of enterprise partners so it's hard to enroll their phones in a MDM programme or to communicate about an entreprise Hub. Unfortunately, For confidentiality reasons, we can't use the Microsoft Marketplace.

We are looking for the simplest way of deploying WP8 apps, without any Microsoft Marketplace or MDM solution. We already have a Microsoft enterprise account.

We already allow users to download Android and iPhone applications just by clicking on a link in the home page of the web site. It's really easy with Android (just a link to the .apk file) and not so hard with iOS (just few stupid certificates, manifest file and strange link).

Comment: It is called "sideloading".  First [google hit](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/jj874388.aspx) looks good:

Comment: Your link goes to a page about windows 8 applications. My need is about Windows **Phone** 8 and there is on Google a lot of things about SD card installation or enterprise hub but nothing about direct app download.